# Large array in database won't load in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I am trying to pull in data from an array into a view to form a chart. The array is stored in a database field and is very large. The array contains around 70k+ smaller arrays that look like this, [1234567890, 5]. Every time I try to render the data in a view it gets cut off. It never loads the full array so the page does not render. No errors are given. Any ideas of what may be causing this?

I am running Ruby 2.0.0-p195, Rails 3.2.13, Postgres 9.2

Comment: It might be time to revisit your schema. An array of 70k+ integer arrays reeks of improper design.

Comment: What do you cut off? it doesn't load the value from db?

Comment: It loads the value from the db just not all of it. It cuts off about a tenth of the way through.

Comment: Have you looked at your web server / rails error logs? PostgreSQL error logs?

Comment: I checked the rails log and found nothing unusual. I don't think we have logging enabled for postgres. I have been wondering if a memory limit or timeout is being hit.

Comment: I am thinking it must be a Nginx or Unicorn setting. I pointed my local development environment to our production database and everything is loading fine. Do Nginx or Unicorn have memory settings that can be changed?

Comment: (i am a member of the posting user's team) To clarify, there is one record in the database that has a text field/column storing a Ruby array with 70K+ items. It is being stored via the postgres_ext gem. So, the database query is returning only one record, but is returning a large amount of data.

Comment: Also, @CraigRinger, thanks for the suggestion of checking the pg logs. Nothing there. Problem must be above PG--in Rails, Unicorn or Nginx.

Comment: What data column are you using for this? hstore, text, string or something else?

Comment: Is the array serialized as yaml, as JSON, or are you hand parsing the text into an array again? Can you add a debugging statement to show the length of the raw string returned by postgresql before parsing, to confirm you're getting the whole string? If it's too short, you know the problem is in fetching the raw data, if it's correct, the problem is not with postgres or the pg gem but with how you parse it into an array and then process the array. Also, garbage collection might become an issue for you, add some memory diagnostics to see what's happening to your memory and GC.

Comment: When I point my local development instance to the production database everything works great. So I think Postgres is off the hook. It must be with Unicorn or Nginx.

Comment: By "works great" you mean how long does it take to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It was not a data limit or Postgres issue. It was a permissions issue with these NGINX config folders:

client_body_temp

fastcgi_temp

proxy_temp

I created those folders in a new location and configured nginx to point to them. Then gave our nginx user access to those folders and everything now works properly.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty weird problem. It could be something timing out during fetching and just returning part of the data, depending on where it timed out.

What I'd check:

- How is the memory usage doing? Does the result improves when I add ram?
- Does it always gets cut off at the same point?
- Do you get data in batch (find_each)? Try playing with the batch size.
- Can the request itself be improved ?
- If the rails logs are fine, try looking at nginx (or whatever you use)

If all options fail try loading this asynchronously by batch by doing multiple ajax calls.